# how to see hidden data in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a signup interface in Django. at first, I have created a form using Django user creation form along with two extra fields. but whenever I submit the form I can not find the data of extra field.
here is the code for form creation:

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserSignUp(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField()
    age=forms.CharField()
    adress=forms.CharField()
    class meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password1','password2','email','age','adress']
```

and here is the view for signup validation

```
def signupuser(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserSignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

    else:
        form=UserSignUp()
    return render(request,"diabetes/signupuser.html",{'form':form})
```

now, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save fields which aren't on the model.

The defautl `django.contrib.auth.models.User` has only the fields:

- username
- password
- email
- first_name
- last_name

The `UserCreationForm` has the "additional"/changed fields:

- password1
- password2

But the fields `age`, `address` aren't on the `User` model and therefore nowhere saved.

You can either [extend the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)  or [use a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)